# How to disable input as select in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have this select:

```
<%= form.input :contact_role_id, as: :select, collection: ContactRole.all %>
```

How would you disable it?

We have tried `disabled: true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `'html' => { :disabled => true }`, such as

```
<%= form.input :contact_role_id, as: :select, collection: ContactRole.all, 'html' => { :disabled => true } %>
```

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html), which talk about using `disabled` but unfortunately does not give an example.